# How to change USERLVL log name to QUERY using pino logger?

Tags: node.js, pinojs

I add the customLevels with `query:35` in the code but nit able to print as QUERY in the terminal.It is printing as below.Could any one suggest on how we can print as QUERY instead of USERLVL.

`2021-10-28 09:25:22.046 +0000] USERLVL(1888 on xxxx)`

code:

```
const logger = pino({
  customLevels: {
    query: 35
  },
prettyPrint: {
    translateTime: true
}});
logger.query('hi');
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, with the above logger i need to print the log statement as `2021-10-28 09:25:22.046 +0000] QUERY(1888 on xxxx) hi ` using pino logger